# SDL Tridion Sites 9.1 > Experience Optimization > Configuration

Tags: content-delivery, experience-optimization, sites-9.1

I am upgrading an instance of SDL Web 8.5 to SDL Tridion Sites 9.1 including Experience Optimization. This requires updating a configuration file for the presentation application (bin\config\smarttarget_conf.xml) for the .NET CIL (Tridion.SmartTarget).

What I can't find anywhere is instruction on how to modify the configuration for the updated XO instance now using elasticsearch instead of Fredhopper.

There are XML elements such as FredHopper that lead me to believe that the XML will have changed significantly but I have no reference documentation at all. The nearest I have come to SDL docs is: https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2/GUID-2301148A-E3EA-43EF-A2FC-7D3C9BAEE8FF?docid=GUID-1B7E5ECF-E1EC-4EA2-AD18-37809635940D but it doesn't provide any XML details other than referencing the filename.

Best,

John

Comment: Based on installation media, looks like the query configuration has moved to bin\config\cd_client_conf.xml. Will test before responding with a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the following document links for the configuration.

[Adding Experience Optimization to your .NET API (RESTful) Role](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2/GUID-662A5331-E96E-4393-B330-7BDEAEF28D23)

[Configuring a .NET website for Experience Optimization](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2/GUID-8DC15425-9B9E-4AA1-B512-46F3CB4108C1)

[Configuring Experience Optimization behavior with the smarttarget_conf file](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2/GUID-5AF77EA5-88B1-47A4-BDC7-8A6C757DC824)

Answer (score 0):

As John notes in comment, the ES query config has moved to the cd_client_conf.xml file as discussed in KB article https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000012174